# How to jump to my application address in bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, boot

I have my bootloader code, and I have to write a function to jump to user application and I have two ways to do that, one in assembly and other in C like follows:

```
void JumpToUserApplication( unsigned int userSP,  unsigned int userStartup)
{
  volatile  unsigned int avoid_optimization;
  avoid_optimization = userSP;       //In order to avoid optimization issue when -Os
  avoid_optimization = userStartup;  //In order to avoid optimization issue when -Os

    // set up stack pointer
  __asm("msr msp, r0");
  __asm("msr psp, r0");

  // Jump to PC (r1)
  __asm("mov pc, r1");
}
```

and

```
void jumpToApplication(void)
{
     void (*fptr)(void);
     fptr = (void (*)(void))0x00002000;
     fptr();
     //__asm__("JUMP #0x00000800H");
}
```

and my user application will start at address 20000. What are the concepts in using the first one and second one? Which one has to be used and which is better?Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `call` instruction is very different from the `C` call. What target have you set while compiling the C code? Depending on the ABI, the call to function pointer may add some unexpected instructions.

Comment: what architecture are you programming for?

Comment: I am using harvard architecture and it is arm cortex m0

Comment: the boot loader should extract the actual application start address from the incoming data.  that is the address that should be jumped to. BTW: 0x2000 is nothing like your stated start address of 0x20000.

Comment: a bootloader, normally, will use the interrupts, The target application will (most likely) use those same interrupts, so careful planning will allow the same interrupt hander code to be used, however, if the interrupt handler has to be different, that needs to be taken care of before calling the start (main) function of the downloaded code